# Asp.net mvc db driven CheckboxList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox

Does any one have any examples for the checkbox List in asp.net mvc 2 . I am looking for a checkbox list populated from the database
table also including a checkbox[all] which should select all the list items.

Answer (score 0):

You can manualy create table with checkboxes, and create checkbox/button with script to select all. Example:

Lets asume YourObject has ID, Name, SomeBool

```
@model IEnumerable<YourObject>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check all</input>

    <div id="chkList">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div>
                    <span>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].ID)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].SomeBool)
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x[i].Name)
                    </span>
                    </div>
                }
    </div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        $("#chkList").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
<script>
```